# Send report to email (HTML)

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I have a procedure with two temporary tables

```
CREATE TABLE #temp       
  ( databasename VARCHAR(100),  
    objectname VARCHAR(100), 
    index_id INT,
    indexname  VARCHAR(100), 
    avg_fragmentation_percent FLOAT,
    indextype VARCHAR(100) 
  )       


CREATE TABLE #temp2       
( 
    databasename VARCHAR(100), 
    objectname VARCHAR(100),
    index_id INT,
    indexname VARCHAR(100), 
    avg_fragmentation_percent FLOAT,
    indextype VARCHAR(100)   
)

INSERT INTO #temp (databasename, 
objectname,index_id, 
indexname,
avg_fragmentation_percent,
indextype)
EXEC master.sys.Sp_msforeachdb
' USE [?] SELECT db_name() as DatabaseName, OBJECT_NAME (a.object_id) as 
 ObjectName,
a.index_id, 
b.name as IndexName, 
avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
index_type_desc
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (db_id(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a 
JOIN sys.indexes AS b
ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id 
WHERE b.index_id <> 0 and avg_fragmentation_in_percent <>0'

INSERT INTO #temp2 (databasename, objectname,index_id, 
indexname,avg_fragmentation_percent,indextype)
EXEC master.sys.Sp_msforeachdb
' USE [?] SELECT db_name() as DatabaseName, OBJECT_NAME (a.object_id) as 
 ObjectName,
a.index_id, 
b.name as IndexName, 
avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
index_type_desc
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (db_id(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a 
JOIN sys.indexes AS b
ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id 
WHERE b.index_id <> 0 and avg_fragmentation_in_percent <>0'
```

and want to send the result from the procedure to email. The problem is that this query works fine but when i execute this its not finding the temporary tables.

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Report</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>ID</th><th>Table</th>' +
    N'<th>Index</th><th>Before fragmentation</th><th>After fragmentation</th>' +
    --N'<th>Expected Revenue</th></tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = T1.databasename,'',
                    td = T1.objectname, '',
                    td = T1.index_id, '',
                    td = T1.indexname, '',
                    td = T1.indextype,'',
                    td = T1.avg_fragmentation_percent AS 
                         avg_fragmentation_percent_pre_change, '',
                    td = T2.avg_fragmentation_percent AS 
                         avg_fragmentation_percent_post_change
              FROM #temp as T1
              INNER JOIN #temp2 AS T2
              ON T1.databasename = T2.databasename
              AND T1.objectname = T2.objectname
              AND T1.index_id = T2.index_id
              AND T1.indexname = T2.indexname
              AND T1.indextype = T2.indextype
              WHERE T1.databasename not in  ('master',
                                             'model',
                                             'msdb',
                                             'tempdb',
                                             'reportServer',
                                             'ReportServerTempDB')             
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='example@mail.com',
@profile_name='example@mail.com',
    @subject = 'Report',
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: Where are the insert statements to the #temp and #temp2 tables?

Comment: Please update it in the question.

Comment: i just update the question

Comment: Sp_send_dbmail opens a separate connection for your query. The #temp table is local to the creating connection. Can you try a global ##temptable instead?

Comment: Dont use a global temptable. Please.

Comment: I have one more question. With this script im testing on AdventureWorks2017. So a lot of indexes have the same results (before 50%, after 50%) and i dont know why. Can someone explain to me why or the script is not good? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your insert to #temp and #temp2 works perfectly fine.

I believe you are getting the below error.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 70 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AS'.

This error is due to the explicit aliasing on the below part of the code.

```
td = T1.avg_fragmentation_percent AS avg_fragmentation_percent_pre_change, '',
td = T2.avg_fragmentation_percent AS avg_fragmentation_percent_post_change
```

since you have already aliased it as 'td'. it will become like this

```
td = T1.avg_fragmentation_percent , '',
td = T2.avg_fragmentation_percent
```

Remove the explicit aliasing using `AS` and run the code and see it works. I did test run 
and it worked.

Comment: @disaster, have you done testing to send an email from db mail? since I suspect an issue will be there for your dbmail. Do send a test mail and confirm your dbmail works

Comment: @disaster, then this should also work fine, so the email is not at all queued or are you getting a blank email?

Comment: @disaster, That can be solved using a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),T1.avg_fragmentation_percent)`

Comment: @disaster if the answer solved your question, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as to let future readers know that this was the solution for your issue. Thanks!